# How to prevent TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple in a 2D array?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently doing the GCSE case study and I need help with my code. I am trying to make a 2D array for a set of data.

Here is the code:

```
#Array
Days = ["Mon1","Tue1","Wed1","Thu1","Fri1","Mon2","Tue2","Wed2","Thu2","Fri2","Mon3","Tue3","Wed3","Thu3","Fri3","Mon4","Tue4","Wed4","Thu4","Fri4"]
Buses = ["A","B","C","D","E","F"]
BusData = [ [0,0,0,2,2], [4,0,3,4,-2], [-5,0,0,3,4], [-1,8,1,1,-2],  #Bus A
            [0,1,0,0,1], [2,0,0,0,0], [1,0,0,0,2], [0,0,1,0,0],   #Bus B
            [2,0,-1,-1,-2], [-2,-3,-1,0,0], [-2,0,1,1,1], [1,-1,-1,2,-2] #Bus C
            [1,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0], [2,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0], #Bus D
            [-1,-1,-1,-2,-4], [-10,-2,0,0,0], [0,1,2,-3,1], [1,3,-1,0,0]  #Bus E
            [0,-5,-5,-5,-4], [-3,-5,0,0,0], [0,-2,-3,1,1], [1,0,0,-2,-5] ] #Bus F

for i in BusData:
    count = 0
    for x in i:
        if x < 0:
            count +=1
    print("Bus {} was late {} times".format(Buses[BusData.index(i)], count))
```

So after I run it I get this error:

[image: this error]

So it seems like there is an error in line 7 (which is `#Bus D`) and I dont get why?

If anyone can answer me with something simple (GCSE level) or modify my code then that would be appreciated as there isnt much time till the exams!

Comment: but why is it specific to bus D?

Comment: sorry, misread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the commas at the end of the data for buses C and E.

This line has a comma at the end:

```
[0,1,0,0,1], [2,0,0,0,0], [1,0,0,0,2], [0,0,1,0,0],   #Bus B
```

But this line doesn't:

```
[2,0,-1,-1,-2], [-2,-3,-1,0,0], [-2,0,1,1,1], [1,-1,-1,2,-2] #Bus C
```